# Find whether a numpy array is a subset of a larger array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subset

I have 2 arrays, for the sake of simplicity let's say the original one is a random set of numbers:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.random.rand(N)
```

Then I sample and shuffle a subset from this array:

```
b=np.array()  <------size<N
```

The shuffling I do do not store the index values, so b is an unordered subset of a

Is there an easy way to get the original indexes of b, so they are in the same order as a, say, if element 2 of b has the index 4 in a, create an array of its assignation.

I could use a for cycle checking element by element, but perhaps there is a more pythonic way

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most computationally efficient thing to do is to keep track of the indices that associate `b` with `a` as `b` is created.

For example, instead of sampling `a`, sample the indices of `a`:

```
indices = random.sample(range(len(a)), k)   # k < N
b = a[indices]
```

Comment: Or, with Numpy (which the OP is already using): `indices = np.arange(len(a)); np.random.shuffle(indices); indices = indices[:k]`

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance `a` happens to be sorted you could do:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a = array([1, 3, 4, 10, 11])
>>> b = array([11, 1, 4])
>>> a.searchsorted(b)
array([4, 0, 2])
```

If `a` is not sorted you're probably best off going with something like @unutbu's answer.